# How to keep menu items intact in all web pages of a website

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a simple website containing an index page with some information. At the top of index page I have a horizontal menu bar like this
[image]

Now, whenever I click on any menu item, a new page opens without retaining the menu bar, i.e., a new page does not show the menu bar. I want to keep the menu bar visible in all the web pages. Another problem I am facing is that 
apart from index page all pages open in full window, I mean to say index page is centralized (having empty left and right sides) but other pages span full screen width. So ,how should I ensure that all pages of website have same width and contain the top menu bar?

Note: Initially I started with some template, but now I am facing these issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The style included in your index page is the thing that centralizes the page, so you have to include that style in all your pages if you want all your pages to have the same style.

There is more than one way to share the menu in all your pages. One thing you can do is to write the menu in a separated HTML file and include that file using the `iframe` tag in all of your pages.